# Boyer-Moore-Horspool implementation

Tags: c, string, search, boyer-moore

I wanted to get Boyer-Moore-Horspool implementation for search of some string in text file. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int bmhSearch(char *needle) {
    FILE *fp;
    int find_result = 0;
    char temp[512];

    size_t nlen = strlen(needle);

    size_t scan = 0;
    size_t bad_char_skip[UCHAR_MAX + 1];
    size_t last;

    if((fopen_s(&fp, "book.txt", "r")) != NULL) {
        return(-1);
    }

    while(fgets(temp, 512, fp) != NULL) {
        size_t hlen = strlen(temp);
        /* pre */
        for (scan = 0; scan <= UCHAR_MAX; scan = scan + 1)
            bad_char_skip[scan] = nlen;
        last = nlen - 1;
        for (scan = 0; scan < last; scan = scan + 1)
            bad_char_skip[needle[scan]] = last - scan;

        while (hlen >= nlen){
            /* scan from the end of the needle */
            char *ptemp = temp;
            for (scan = last; ptemp[scan] == needle[scan]; scan = scan - 1){
                if (scan == 0){
                    find_result++;
                }
            }

            hlen     -= bad_char_skip[ptemp[last]];
            ptemp += bad_char_skip[ptemp[last]];
            printf("%d\t%d\n", hlen, nlen);
        }
    }

    if(fp) {
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return find_result;
}

int main(void){
    char needle[30] = {"some text like this"};
    printf("Matches found: %d\n", bmhSearch(needle);
}
```

I believe, there is tons of things I did wrong, but I really can't find and fix it.
The only thing I've got is on some stage the program doesn't comply with the condition `while(hlen >= nlen)`.

Comment: What is your problem? If you don't have anything specific and just want a code review, go to CodeReview SE. People here like to solve programming problems. People like to say what's wrong with other's codes.

Comment: Step 1: Separate your string search from things like file reading. Step 2: fire up the debugger.

Comment: @luk32: Code Review.SE is *only* for code that *works*.

Comment: @JerryCoffin OP *believes* his code is wrong, and haven't named a single thing that doesn't work. So maybe he just needs a review.

Comment: @luk32 If only i knew what are the problems, I don't think i would create this post. :)
By the way, I used the debugger to try figuring out what's wrong. So I think 'hlen' varible is overflowed, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I have troubles believing that you did anything with the code at all, because it should not compile as of now. But I hope I am wrong. Also how do you know if there are any problems, if you cannot present even one? It's way harder to say what mistakes you did, if you do not tell what's wrong. Not to mention the site politely asks for "a simple self contained code example that singles out the problem" in "How to ask" tutorial.

Comment: @luk32 It's simple, i compiled it, it printed me nothing, so I got that something is wrong. I tried very hard to solve it myself, but I can't find the place with mistake.

Comment: I doubt you compiled code presented here, because you have an unmatched parentheses on this line `printf("Matches found: %d\n", bmhSearch(needle);`.

Comment: @luk32 Not this one, you are right. I tried to show a problem place in this code.

Comment: Problem is solved. I shouldn't have to edit the BMH implementation I found, I just had to process the returned result of it. Thanks for help, and I'm very sorry that I've asked so stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is "What's wrong with the code?"; here are a few things to start with:

```
 printf("Matches found: %d\n", bmhSearch(needle); // Missing a final ')'.
```

---

```
 int main(void)
    {
    ...
    return(0);  // Something like this line is required for a function that returns'int'.
    }
```

---

```
     size_t bad_char_skip[UCHAR_MAX + 1];  // Requires: '#include <limits.h>
```

---

```
     if((fopen_s(&fp, "book.txt", "r")) != NULL) {
```

The function 'fopen_s()' does not return a pointer.  It returns an errno_t type, which is an integer value.  Comparing an integer with 'NULL' is like showing up at the 'Indian war-dance' dressed as a cowboy.  Perhaps the following is more appropriate:

```
     if((fopen_s(&fp, "book.txt", "r")) != 0) {
```

which is equivalent to (my favorite):

```
     if(fopen_s(&fp, "book.txt", "r")) {
```

---

```
        printf("%d\t%d\n", hlen, nlen);
```

The above format string is incorrect.  it should be:

```
        printf("%zu\t%zu\n", hlen, nlen);
```

---

In a strict C sense, the following lines need attention:

```
        bad_char_skip[needle[scan]] = last - scan;

        hlen  -= bad_char_skip[ptemp[last]];
        ptemp += bad_char_skip[ptemp[last]];
```

They should be changed to the following:

```
        bad_char_skip[(int)needle[scan]] = last - scan;

        hlen  -= bad_char_skip[(int)ptemp[last]];
        ptemp += bad_char_skip[(int)ptemp[last]];
```

The variable 'ptemp' is defineded as a 'char *'.  Hence; 'ptemp[n]' evaluates as a 'char' type; while an array index number must be 'int'.